# problem with k3b not burning audio cd's

Tags: cd, burning

I set up k3b (actually a friend converted my computer to Linux) and put a blank cd in my drive, select the songs I want to burn, and push burn. I get a sound and this message:

```
cdrecord has no permission to open the device.
Modify device settings in k3b to solve this problem.
```

But I don't have 'device settings to push! I tried ripping a pre-done cd and k3b rips it just fine.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2347009 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.